# Wix , Install windows service insufficient privellages error

Tags: wix, windows-services, windows-installer

I want to install a windows service , so I followed all the recommendations by adding a user with privilege , but while starting the service give error check if you have sufficient privilege , below is the wix part I use

```
<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="MedecxService_ServiceComponents">
        <Component Id="MedecxService_ServiceComponent" Directory="MedecxService_INSTALLFOLDER" Guid="ab621e57-b52d-4bbe-853e-a5f0ca312a73">
            <File Id="fil1DBD278DE49E2EF052BB6AD6321F3F88" Source="$(var.SourceOutput)\BarcodeLib.dll" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="filC2A7B546D16126D43DBD2D104D432F8E" Source="$(var.SourceOutput)\BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="fil7DFD2A683DC5DD9AE627D7E981F10CF0" Source="$(var.SourceOutput)\EntityFramework.dll" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="filA912EE64A53B15C1D42E5728EB204CE7" Source="$(var.SourceOutput)\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="fil753895A598A12643844071A70FA84CE0" Source="$(var.SourceOutput)\EntityFramework.SqlServer.xml" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="filFC1348D75FED056A10197E522A36B6BA" Source="$(var.SourceOutput)\EntityFramework.xml" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="fil7252DEC8E62AECCABE47731A9AD8AF8F" Source="$(var.SourceOutput)\Excel.dll" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="fil2CE2A8A8259B04B3F97DD1DAFE40EDB7" Source="$(var.SourceOutput)\Helpers.dll" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="filC4FB21276BDBCDD1F4E7BF8A7F45C4A5" Source="$(var.SourceOutput)\ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="fil42C2BC798D2D94A68DDD00C91ABA994E" Source="$(var.SourceOutput)\installSVC.bat" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="filB02D1566FC3DC0D161ABD38AD5FC64DC" Source="$(var.SourceOutput)\InstallUtil.InstallLog" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="fil954AFA2395EEF3231797A75EDB77B0BE" Source="$(var.SourceOutput)\Ksys.BusinessLayer.dll" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="fil7ACD4014B5B636037386C4BDF79C1B78" Source="$(var.SourceOutput)\Ksys.Config.dll" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="fil9D674EB595DEF40D9EB7E7F9385692F8" Source="$(var.SourceOutput)\Ksys.DataAccessLayer.dll" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="fil5C85C3A51F97BECB30D1FD009D0A8F40" Source="$(var.SourceOutput)\Ksys.EF.dll" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="filA856B94EF75EB5736F2FF15FFE9282AE" Source="$(var.SourceOutput)\ksys.logger.dll" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="fil663E50F269D1C3C837A6CCF85F2A9300" Source="$(var.SourceOutput)\Ksys.Model.dll" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="filA0113B26097E9D1E15349612C1220CD4" Source="$(var.SourceOutput)\Ksys.Serializer.dll" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="fil5D63BB77482AF07C528276A85E2DA9EA" Source="$(var.SourceOutput)\LinqKit.dll" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="filE10B7796C9698A8AFAC095C006D48B28" Source="$(var.SourceOutput)\LinqKit.xml" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="fil533B9EB0CA736575A79518F23236D1E0" Source="$(var.SourceOutput)\MedexCloudWindowsService.exe" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="filFFC294FA751B1E0AFB84F1F322CD0074" Source="$(var.SourceOutput)\MedexCloudWindowsService.exe.config" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="fil69C4144F6FBAFBE9D9BEE80F9EE9F166" Source="$(var.SourceOutput)\MedexCloudWindowsService.InstallLog" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="fil4CA61FA9154292B5DEACC620C7D7CFBE" Source="$(var.SourceOutput)\MedexCloudWindowsService.InstallState" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="fil7F15BA8094994ADAD04DA907E934B5BD" Source="$(var.SourceOutput)\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="fil9BA73B8312B77DA2A8D16A6C05D0598B" Source="$(var.SourceOutput)\Newtonsoft.Json.xml" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="fil49D7CB3EEC543B549EE3BE62A5F30A21" Source="$(var.SourceOutput)\NLog.config" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="filD99192F3EF926B0696A896924D4A93A9" Source="$(var.SourceOutput)\NLog.dll" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="fil88CDAADE20F6C0BABA487DCEA46ED96F" Source="$(var.SourceOutput)\NLog.xml" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="fil5AEDF8895277D5A2AA598DDAFF1864E9" Source="$(var.SourceOutput)\PF.SecurityEngine.dll" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="fil1F3080066204F089C69EB71515856B08" Source="$(var.SourceOutput)\Telerik.Windows.Controls.dll" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="filD55FBBEEEACF8F9178263C092CE65233" Source="$(var.SourceOutput)\Telerik.Windows.Controls.Input.dll" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="filDC7E32BCE263A15047412BEF5CA27BB9" Source="$(var.SourceOutput)\Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation.dll" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="fil51DF87675977D541123ACB4D746195AE" Source="$(var.SourceOutput)\Telerik.Windows.Controls.ScheduleView.dll" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="fil426643C3E4EA3F59203804FB1B3737A6" Source="$(var.SourceOutput)\Telerik.Windows.Data.dll" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="fil74FBFF28BAE103F0D04C443B98393E70" Source="$(var.SourceOutput)\UninstallSVC.bat" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="filDE20D180F79A557C4356E0E6A2F651EA" Source="$(var.SourceOutput)\Ar-EG\Helpers.resources.dll" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="fil23324D44B270D2DDB61E42F72C82FA42" Source="$(var.SourceOutput)\Culture\Resources.Ar-EG.Designer.cs" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="fil309B641D96FFD04503F6706E7832137E" Source="$(var.SourceOutput)\Culture\Resources.Ar-EG.resx" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="fil5131FA2051CE202BE8A87A73423D3188" Source="$(var.SourceOutput)\Culture\Resources.Designer.cs" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="fil4B63438F9C7A1A62CE7519085FD7EF7F" Source="$(var.SourceOutput)\Culture\Resources.EN-US.Designer.cs" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="fil88BF0A38DDF70B974AE6154BCD6B56DA" Source="$(var.SourceOutput)\Culture\Resources.EN-US.resx" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="filC98495569CBB3CCB9CCC9B0F550AB54C" Source="$(var.SourceOutput)\Culture\Resources.resx" Vital="yes" />
            <File Id="filCC289B0C10B0E547830E23254F453E0E" Source="$(var.SourceOutput)\EN-US\Helpers.resources.dll" Vital="yes" />
            <util:User Id="user" CreateUser="yes" Name="serviceaccount" Password="p2Ekutrekac34ph2" LogonAsService="yes" UpdateIfExists="yes" RemoveOnUninstall="yes" PasswordNeverExpires="yes" FailIfExists="no" Domain="[ComputerName]" CanNotChangePassword="yes" Disabled="no" PasswordExpired="no" />
            <ServiceInstall Id="QBServiceInstaller" Type="ownProcess" Vital="yes" Name="MedexCloudWindowsService.exe" DisplayName="medexCloud Backend service" Description="medexCloud Backend service" Start="auto" Account=".\serviceaccount" Password="p2Ekutrekac34ph2" ErrorControl="ignore" Interactive="no" />
            <ServiceControl Id="MedecxServiceStartService" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" Name="MedexCloudWindowsService.exe" Wait="yes" />
        </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

Comment: So it definitely is error 1920, just to confirm?

Comment: @PhilDW Exactly error 1920

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "insufficient privilege" error is just a guess, and isn't often the cause of the issue. So, I'll list the usual suspects:

1. The service code is broken in the startup area, having responded to the start message or OnStart event, it is then crashing or not responding to the start in a timely manner. This can be tested by having the service create a trace log of what it's doing, which is invaluable anyway to help debug services.
2. It's got a missing dependency that is either a) Not included in the install or prerequisites or b) Is being installed to the GAC or WinSxS and is therefore not available when the service is started.
3. Your WiX is incorrect somewhere. This actually seems the most likely cause based on what I can see of your source. ServiceInstall requires that the service binary be the keypath of the containing component. As far as I can tell, your service exe is not the keypath of the component, so it's not clear to me that your service would be installed correctly. In any case, best practice is to have one file per component.